# doubt on private members and Methods

Tags: java

i have doubt in Private fields, variables and methods, if i created a class that contains private variables and methods then how can i use, when to go for private members, methods and when to not use?

Comment: your question isn't clear, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I clearly failed trying to disentangle what you have just said. Rewrite it please!

Comment: it is simple when to go for private fields and methods?----this for brydgesk and jweyrich

Answer (score 2):

Private members (methods are members too) are how you implement **Encapsulation** which is arguably the most important concept in object oriented programming.

The idea is to distinguish between concrete implementation details and an abstract interfaces. The abstract interface specifies *what* a class does, it's used by other classes and should not change often. That's what publich members are for.

Private members, on the other hand, are implementation details: other classes should not use or even know about them, because they are likely to change much more often.

Answer (score 1):

**Private** - only that particular class needs access to them.  Nothing outside the class can see or use them.

**Protected** - that particular class and any class that extends that class can access them.  Classes that do not extend the member's class cannot see or use them.

**Public** - any other class can access, see and use them.

I learnt today that Java also has another access level which is implied if you don't specify public/protected/private.  This is called "package private" and means classes within the same package can access the members, but no class outside of the package can.

[This page](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) might also help you out.

Comment: Well, all classes from same package can access protected fields.

Comment: @Tadeusz - sorry, I'm not a Java programmer, I wrongly assumed the definitions of public/protected/private were the same across OOP langauges.  In that case, what's the difference between "protected" and "package private"?

Comment: proteced provides visibility to child classes (even across the package boundaries) where as with package private visibility is only to the types inside the same package.

Answer (score 1):

You should always give members of a class the most restrictive visibility level possible.  You can use private members of a class in any method contained in that class.

Answer (score 1):

Private members can only be accessed from inside the class. That is very useful, to avoid tainting the API of the class. If you declare a method as public, every outside class can use it and depends on it. Later you break code, if you want to change it. If it is private, the change is restricted to the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

The principle of encapsulation when applied to Java (roughly) states that fields should be private and the values accessed by getXXX() and setXXX() methods.

Private methods are methods that are only internal to the class they're in, and have no use outside of that class.

Comment: I have to add that it's stupid to add getters and setters (getXXX() and setXXX()) blindly for any private variable. Always ask yourself if others _really_, _really_ need to set or even get the variable or if the only access should be through methods which have more logic. Example: bankAccount.withdraw(amount) implies that there are checks going on while bankAccount.setAmount(bankAccount.getAmount() - amount) implies blind modification. Better yet: reduce it to bankAccount.transfer(targetAccount, amount) so the only way to modify the account is by transfering money, which avoids many problems.

Comment: @dbemerlin:  Hence the word "roughly" above.  I completely agree with you.  In a case like a BankAccount class, it's easy to define methods that don't hint at the structure: deposit(double amt), withdraw(double amt), transfer(BankAccount acct, double amt).  It's not so easy as classes represent objects more far removed from things we are familiar with.  For example, setting the properties of a Swing component.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Sun tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

> **Tips on Choosing an Access Level**: If other programmers use your class,
>   you want to ensure that errors from
>   misuse cannot happen. Access levels
>   can help you do this. Use the most
>   restrictive access level that makes
>   sense for a particular member.
>
> - Use
>     `private` unless you have a good reason
>     not to.
> - Avoid `public` fields except for
>     constants. (Many of the examples in
>     the tutorial use public fields. This
>     may help to illustrate some points
>     concisely, but is not recommended for
>     production code.) Public fields tend
>     to link you to a particular
>     implementation and limit your
>     flexibility in changing your code.

Comment: My philosophy tends to be "Use `protected` unless you have a good reason not to". It's too easy to make a member private without realising that a subclass might need to access it at some point in the not-so-distant future. I only use `private` or `public` when I have a good case for either. This is not to say I don't use `private` members, more often than not, I do. I just make sure that it's what I _really_ want to do before I make something `private`.

Comment: @Chinmay: IMHO this approach imply that your design relies on implementation inhertiance which might be inappropriate.

Comment: @Chinmay: you make a valid point, but IMHO it stems from insufficient testing and design in the first place. Once you make a member protected, it represents a commitment to an implementation detail. A protected member is part of the class's exported API and must be supported **forever**. Citing Bloch in Effective Java, *the only way to test a class designed for inheritance is to write subclasses*.

Comment: This is true in an ideal world, but I tend to have to work heavily with biologists who dabble in programming rather than full-time programmers and so this approach works well. Pre-designed software is a luxury in my world :)

Answer (score 0):

if write Separate JDBC class for Connection method as private what happen. so cant use that connection method in my class deff...

Answer (score 0):

A class only with private members and methods is an immuatable class, which makes it a good candidate for usage as key in Map. However you need to provide a non-private constructor and properly override `hashCode` and `equals` method.

Answer (score 0):

Public and protected members are part of your classes exported API. Private and so-called package private access levels are part of the internal implementation.

You should use the lowest possible access level by default - private followed by package private - unless you have a good reason not to. I notice some developers use protected by default. This is not advised since protected is part of the API that classes in external packages can use if they are able to extend your class. If you did not anticipate/design for the extension of your class this is can lead to unfortunate side effects.

See Effective Java, 2nd Ed. for a far better explanation:

Item 13: Minimize the accessibility of classes and members

Item 17: Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it

Quote:

"The single most important factor that distinguishes a well-designed module from a
poorly designed one is the degree to which the module hides its internal data and
other implementation details from other modules."

Answer (score 0):

I think you've had had quite enough answers for now. Your question let me know that u r just beggining to use the Language, i'll strongly recommend you to get a copy of Joshua Bloch *"Effective Java"*, he explains not just what does the language do, but more importantly how to use it effectively. As in this case, why choose private members over package, public or protected ones. Regards